# Moviepy - TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, moviepy

```
from moviepy.editor import *
clip = VideoFileClip("vid.mov")
clip.write_videofile("movie.mp4")
```

^ Gives the error

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly.
```

It prints "Building video movie.mp4" and "Writing audio in movieTEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp3" normally.

I am using python 3.2 with Raspian Wheezy.
What is wrong? Surely it should be a simple program...

EDIT:
If you add audio = false to the write_videofile parameters, it works fine. The problem is somewhere in the audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/330) answer, the issue was that there is an error in the moviepy script which generates an incorrect error output. The correct output indicates that I had not install the libmp3lame codec when I installed ffmpeg, so it could not write audio. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40021623/installing-libmp3lame-to-work-with-ffmpeg-on-raspberry-pi/40022016#40022016) for details on how to correctly install ffmpeg with aforementioned codec.