# Installing libmp3lame to work with FFMPEG on raspberry pi

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, mp3, codec

I am using the moviepy module with python 3.2 on my RPi 2. It uses FFMPEG to read and write the video, so I installed FFMPEG using [these](http://hannes.enjoys.it/blog/2016/03/ffmpeg-on-raspbian-raspberry-pi/) instructions to the letter. Now when I run the program, it says that my video export failed because FFMPEG didn't find the libmp3lame codec that it needs. How do I got about installing the libmp3lame codec onto my RPi 2 (running Raspian Wheezy)?

I think I have to reinstall FFMPEG to install the codec.. how do I do that correctly?

Comment: libshine MP3 encoder may be significantly faster than libmp3lame on ARM. (But I'm not sure since I've never tried it).

Comment: May be, but moviepy doesn't automatically use it, and I wouldn't know how to change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, install lame mp3 with

```
sudo apt-get install libmp3lame-dev
```

and then recompile/build ffmpeg including the `--enable-libmp3lame` flag

```
./configure <other-configure-options> --enable-libmp3lame
```

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to uninstall `ffmpeg` first, but yes, `sudo make uninstall` is the way to do it.